# How do you plot vertical 3D planes?

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d

[see picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VruIF.png)

Hey, I want to plot a function in 3d matplotlib python. The functions I want to plot are x = i where i stretches from 0 to 1 with increments of 0.20. So basically 4 vertical planes just as in the picture I shared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create the planes as surface plots.

Here's an example:

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np

X, Y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(-6, 6), np.arange(-6, 6))
Z = 0*X

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, alpha=0.5)  # the horizontal plane
ax.plot_surface(Z, Y, X, alpha=0.5)  # the vertical plane
```